# using the .strip method with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strip

As part of my validation for a user name I need to strip the white space from the beginning and end of the user input. I know that the .strip method will do this for me but I'm unsure how to use this method.

At what point do I strip the white spaces off a user input? 
should it be in the form where the info is taken in? Or in the controller or model?

Comment: can you add the code in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in a callback in the model.

```
before_save :strip_username

private
def strip_username
  self.username.strip!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it at the controller level, especially since this is pre-processing logic, something like removing whitespace should be done at the controller level.

Now, if removing whitespace is common and would always need to be done, say, on creating a new record, then a `before_filter` on the model would make sense - it all depends on what your form is doing.